# Unable to run tests as they are skipping

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2017, automated-tests

Error Message: Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Getting below error after running script in MS VS Enterprise 2017

```
[6/19/2018 6:57:11 PM Informational] ------ Load Playlist started ------
[6/19/2018 6:57:11 PM Informational] ========== Load Playlist finished (0:00:00.0069995) ==========
[6/19/2018 6:57:39 PM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[6/19/2018 6:57:41 PM Informational] SpecRun: not SpecRun assembly - skip: C:\AmberATF_Code\AutomatedAcceptanceTests\src\Microlise.Test.Acceptance\bin\Debug\Microlise.Test.Acceptance.dll
[6/19/2018 6:57:41 PM Warning] No test is available in C:\AmberATF_Code\AutomatedAcceptanceTests\src\Microlise.Test.Acceptance\bin\Debug\Microlise.Test.Acceptance.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
[6/19/2018 6:57:41 PM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:01.7210115) ==========
```